# What is the usage of local-exec provisioner?

Tags: ansible, terraform

I am getting familiar with Terraform and Ansible through books. Could someone enlighten me about the following block of code?

```
provisioner "local-exec" { 
    command = "ansible-playbook -u ubuntu --key-file ansible-key.pem -T 300 -i '${self.public_ip},', app.yml" 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is local-exec is for anything you want to do on your local machine instead of the remote machine.

You can do a bunch of different things:

- write an ssh key into your `~/.ssh` to access the server
- run a `sleep 30` or something to make sure the next commands wait a bit for your machine to provision
- write logs to your local directory (last run, date completed, etc.)
- write some env_vars to your local machine you can use to access the machine
- the ansible example you provided

FYI, hashicorp *hates* `local-` and `remote-` exec. If you talk to one of their devs, they will tell you that it is a necessary evil. Other than maybe a sleep or write this or that, avoid it for any stateful data.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret that as Terraform should execute a local command on the Control Node.

Reading the documentation about [`local-exec` Provisioner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) it turns out that

> *The `local-exec` provisioner invokes a local executable after a (annot.: remote) resource is created. This invokes a process on the machine running Terraform ...*

and not on the Remote Resource.

So after Terraform has in example created a Virtual Machine, it calls an Ansible playbook to proceed further on it.